# No device file can be found for /dev/agp*

Tags: arch-linux, kernel

I have a vega 8 laptop with the AMD Ryzen 5 2500U running arch linux with the 5.15.63-1-lts kernel. I noticed that there is no agp file in `/dev/` even though the `agpgart` module seems to be loaded. When I check my dmesg:

```
[    0.731497] ACPI: \_PR_.C007: Found 2 idle states
[    0.731772] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.733777] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    0.733779] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.733830] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 loaded and initialized
[    0.734827] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:02:00.0
[    0.734884] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
```

the kernel module seems to be loaded but when I grep the contents of /dev/ I cant find a device file and `lsmod` doesnt show any agp module loaded. When I run `doas modprobe agpgart` to try to load the module it returns without any output to stdout and `lsmod` and dmesg dont change.

Is there any way that I could get the device file and the module to load?

Comment: Your system doesn’t have AGP, do you actually need the device file?

Comment: @StephenKitt I was under the assumption that PCI AMD gpus provided AGP as UMS xf86-video-ati accessed AGP resources though drm as a requirement for DRI.

Comment: Your system uses PCI Express, not AGP, and [AGP support, including `agpgart`, is only relevant on actual AGP systems](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.5/source/drivers/char/agp/Kconfig).

Comment: Oh, I guess I could use PCI allocations but I dont know how to do it(more of a me problem especially here), thanks for the answer.